# Should I store promises in Redux?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I'm using Redux and React in an online food-ordering app.

When the user removes an item from their basket, I need to fire off an XHR request to the server to compute the new total price for the basket. When this XHR completes, I update the redux store and render the new price. I'm using Redux thunk to manage this async operation.

There is a problem is a user removes two items from the basket in quick succession. The user removes the first item, and I fire off an XHR to get the new price. Then the user clicks a button to remove a second item, and a second XHR is fired off.

The UI will be in an incorrect state if the second XHR completes before the first - the price of the basket with only the first item removed will be shown.

To work around this, I want to cancel the first (in-flight) XHR when the user clicks the button to remove the second item. To cancel the first XHR I need to keep track of the promise object (I'm using [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) to manage XHR).

It makes sense to me to store the in-flight XHR in the redux store. Is it bad practice to store promises in Redux like this? It seems to be frowned upon - Redux should really just be storing plain data.

Comment: This is the first time I hear about storing promises in the Redux app state. I think there might be a better way than that. Why don't you prevent the user from doing anything while you make that request (like, disable the ability to do anything by showing a loading icon)? I think coming up with a simpler solution would be best. If you really want to get into cancelling promises, check the bottom of this page: `https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html`. Or you could look into RxJS.

Comment: this would be quick work with redux-observable https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable can replace your one thunk with an epic here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is covered in the Redux FAQ, at http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-non-serializable :

> It is highly recommended that you only put plain serializable objects, arrays, and primitives into your store. It's technically possible to insert non-serializable items into the store, but doing so can break the ability to persist and rehydrate the contents of a store, as well as interfere with time-travel debugging.

Generally, any async behavior like this is handled externally to the Redux store, via promises or middleware like redux-thunk, redux-saga, or redux-observable.  For some comparisons between these approaches, see the recent articles [Redux 4 Ways](https://medium.com/react-native-training/redux-4-ways-95a130da0cdc) and [3 Common Approaches to Side-Effects in Redux](https://goshakkk.name/redux-side-effect-approaches/).