# How to handle expired jwt token in react redux?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux

I'm developing the application with react js and redux. For backend i used java to create api's. So far i have created three services, login, signup, listing. I have used jwt token for listing service to secure the incformation. I have set jwt token expiration time is 10 mins in backend. Each 10 mins the jwt token will get expired and for new token i need to login again. This is what i have done in backend.

I have integrated those services in my react with redux concept. The problem which i'm getting is, each i need to go login screen for new token. I want this to be happen in background. How to do with redux?

```
export function handleResponse(response) {
  if (response.ok) {
    return response.json();
  }
  // If invalid jwt token the page will get redirect to login.
  if (response.status === 401) {
    localStorage.clear();
    alert('Session expired!');
    location.href = '/login';
  }
}

export function loginAction(data) {
  const resObject = {
    username: data.username,
    password: data.password,
  };
  return dispatch =>
    fetch(`/login`, {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify(resObject),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Basic ${basicAuth.authSecret}`,
      },
    })
      .then(handleResponse)
      .then(res => dispatch(loginUser(res)));
}
```

Comment: Your API should implement an API Endpoint for refreshing Tokens.
I faced a similiar problem, but i'm using django rest framework jwt which already ships an api endpoint  for this case.
Then you'll need an action, saga and reducer which sends your current jwt to the endpoint and returns a new one if the old one was valid.
You could then easily trigger the refresh token action every time the user does a succesfull post/delete/put request to the api

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Redux to refresh JWT token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36948557/how-to-use-redux-to-refresh-jwt-token)

Comment: What about cases where you'd want a user to manually request a token on another page, which may require them to provide some information for security reasons rather than automatically refreshing the token, which is potentially a security hole.