# React + redux + axios + thunk, wait for interceptors.response refresh token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios, redux-thunk

I used redux and redux-thunk, and use `axios interceptors response` for refresh token, my code is:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    return response;
}, error => {
    if (error.response && error.response.data.error === 'token_expired') {
        axios.get('/refresh')
            .then(response => {
                let newToken = response.data.newToken;
                dispatch(refreshToken(newToken))
                error.config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + newToken;
                console.log(error.config);
                return axios.request(error.config);
            });
    } else {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
});
```

My code work and token refresh, but redux action doesn't wait for `axios.interceptors.response` and before refresh token retrun `undefined`

who can i fix this?

**Update**

I change my code to:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    return response;
}, error => {
    if (error.response && error.response.data.error === 'token_expired') {
        dispatch(getNewToken(newToken => {
            error.config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + newToken;
            return axios.request(error.config);
        }))
    } else {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
});
```

and getNewToken is:

```
export const getNewToken = (onSuccess) => {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.get('/refresh')
            .then(response => {
                let newToken = response.data.newToken;
                dispatch(refreshToken(newToken))
                onSuccess(newToken);
            });
    }
}
```

when i check browser web developer, in network this work and request repeat with new token and works, but my action dosn't run again to render response

where is my wrong?

**Update2:**

my middleware:

```
const jwtTokenRefresh = ({ dispatch, getState }) => (next => (action) => {
    const timeStamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    const expiration = getState().auth.expiration;
    if (expiration && timeStamp > expiration) {

        axios.get('/refresh')
            .then(response => {
                let newToken = response.data.newToken;
                dispatch(refreshToken(newToken))
            })
            .then(() => {
                next(action);
            })
    }else {
        return next(action);
    }
});
```

and refresh token action:

```
export const refreshToken = dispatch => {
    return dispatch => {
        axios.get('/refresh')
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
                let newToken = response.data.newToken;
                const rememberMe = localStorage.getItem('token') ? true : false;
                dispatch(authSuccess(newToken, rememberMe))
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36948557/how-to-use-redux-to-refresh-jwt-token

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36948557/how-to-use-redux-to-refresh-jwt-token

Comment: thank you, i want check server response, if has error and error equal token_expired refresh token and repeat request, are there any way?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass setting new token as a callback function to refreshToken() action and invoke it when refreshToken returns success result:

```
dispatch(refreshToken((newToken) => {
    error.config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + newToken;
    console.log(error.config);
    return axios.request(error.config);
  })
)
```

And *refreshToken* action is something like

```
refreshToken(onSuccess, onFailure) {
     axios.post('/refreshTokenUrl')
     .then(responseData => {
         const {token} = responseData;
         onSuccess(token);
     })
}
```

Comment: thank you, i checked it and edit my question, please checked it again.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work this way? Is onSuccess() called with new token?
And i'd recommend you instead of   _error.config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + newToken;_  use _axios.defaults.headers.Authorization = newToken_, so axios will send new token in all requests

Comment: I have a action called `fetchItems`, when run it, if token is not expired it works, but if token is expired my new code works and refresh tokon and if check developer tools fetshed items, but `fetchItems` not run again to get items and render it

Comment: i use `axios.interceptors.request` and in every request get token from redux, my problem is when server response is `token_expired` and i want get new token and resend again request and now run my action (here my action called `fetchItems` )

Comment: To retry redux actions you should implement jwtTokenRefresh middleware and use it in your store (the link I provided in first comment). I tried it once and it worked for me. Here is the link to my code,maybe it will help you https://pastebin.com/HGZWCpUc . Pay attention to onSuccessRefresh() function. That is where action called again after success refresh. And if you decide to use it, don't forget to apply it as middleware to your store.

Comment: this middleware check token expire time by local time before send request and if token is expired refresh token, but i want check in server, clock of some of my users computer is wrong ‍♂️ and it make a problem.

Comment: this middleware check token expire time by local time before send request and if token is expired refresh token, but i want check in server, clock of some of my users computer is wrong ‍♂️ and it make a problem. – Masoud92m 9 mins ago

Comment: As I can see in different resources, everybody is also sending token and its expiration time from backend . You can send it as Unix time stamp and convert user local time to Unix time stamp and compare it. I may have too few experience, but I don’t know, how to do it another way. I’ve told you everything I know =)

Comment: I do believe there must be some way to «save» redux action and ,when first attempt fails, retry it after refreshing token, but idk how to handle it. Checking expiration on user side doesn’t mean that you don’t need it on backend. You certainly will check if token expired on backend too!

Comment: thanks a lot. i use laravel in backend and in checked token is expired, i want try refresh with middleware and check expire with local time stamp, I will tell you the result

Comment: Ok, please inform if you deal with it!

Comment: I'm totally confused, i tried multiple way to get new token and dispatch it, but i can, when can i set new token to axios? i edited my question, please check update2, thank you

Comment: Why are you doing _axios.get('/refresh')_ 2 times - inside _jwtTokenRefresh_and inside _refreshToken_ redux action? Also you need to compare tokenExpiration time and local time for some difference in seconds - for instance, if token you have 5 second left until token will be expired. Here is a link for approximate code https://pastebin.com/YJvDcFdm

Comment: changed my code like your help, please check it: https://pastebin.com/yFPgCmth, but when token expired and dispatch refreshToken, my cpu usage become to 100% and browser crashed,

Comment: Are there any errors or warnings in browser console? The code seems correct to me. Try debugging, does your code come to axios.get('/refresh')? Does it come to success-callback and set new token to headers?

Comment: i can't check console. because when token expired my cpu usage become to 100% and browser freezes, i kill it from command line, axios.get('/refresh') is correct, i fetched token before, but i can't set new token ‍♂️

Comment: Add debugger; inside success token get and check, if the code will come there

Comment: i wrote very simple action called `sayHi` to test dispatch, please check it https://pastebin.com/RYbQuFmH, but i getting error `InternalError: too much recursion` where is my wrong? can you help me? thank you.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that sayHi() must return some value, because it's an action creator. Check this https://github.com/rajdee/redux/blob/master/docs/basics/Actions.md.

Comment: Also check again this response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36948557/how-to-use-redux-to-refresh-jwt-token. As you can see, current executing refresh token promise is saved to local variable freshTokenPromise. You can create this variable in your reducer. That'll help you avoid creating multiple identical refreshToken requests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190286/discussion-between-ifsogirl-and-masoud92m).